# Exporting multiple jars in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, export

I want to export different packages of my Java project into different JAR files.
The packages are like this:

- com.example.package
- com.example.otherpackage
- ...

What I want is export it to some folder so that it looks like this:

jars/
-> package.jar
-> otherpackage.jar

How can I do that?

(I know I can export the full jar, but I want them separate. I also know that I can select what jars to export, and that in this case I could export the two jars separately, but if I have 500 jars, this would really hurt my fingers, so I'm looking for a bit more automated solution).

Answer (score -1):

Go to

> Navigator view > right click on the package and click export > Select
>   Jar in drop down> click next > give a name > click finish.

Voila

Comment: Maybe I understand you wrong, but as I said in the parentheses, I wanted a solution for multiple jars. I already know how to export a single package.

Comment: Gotcha. So you want to have something magical which will export individual packages from one project to individual  jars. Right ? If so, you have to individually do it for every package. If this is a repeated requirement, you will be better off writing an ant script/mvn (m2eclipse, may be) to do this for you. HTH

Comment: I hate it when someone begs for some reputation. Also, I may not have much reputation, but I don't like to be treated as a noob. If I didn't mark your answer as accepted, it's because it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: @TwinOneAndroid Beg ? I just reminded you of this forums etiquette. Read what I wrote, I can understand that English may not be your first language. No one cares what you like or hate, btw.